# Prove that $\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{x+n^2}=\frac{\pi\sqrt{x}\operatorname{coth}(\pi\sqrt{x})-1}{2x}$ for all $x>0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, hyperbolic-functions

Wolfram Alpha gives the following equality, which seems to be valid for all $x>0$ :

$$\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{x+n^2}=\frac{\pi\sqrt{x}\operatorname{coth}(\pi\sqrt{x})-1}{2x}$$

My question is : how to prove it ?

Note that taking $x\to 0$ yields the famous $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ on both sides, which is comforting.

---

**EDIT** : This proof is inspired from Atmos's answer on Fourier coefficients. Let us denote $S=\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{x+n^2}$.

Define $f_\alpha:x\in]-\pi,\pi]\mapsto e^{\alpha x}$. Its complex Fourier coefficients are $$c_n(f_\alpha)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f_\alpha(t) e^{-int}\:dt\\
=\frac{(-1)^n\sinh(\alpha \pi)}{\pi}\frac{1}{\alpha-in}
$$
Recall the Parseval equality
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} |c_n(f_\alpha)|^2 = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f_\alpha(x)|^2\:dx \label{eqn1}\tag{1}$$

The left-hand-side of \eqref{eqn1} is related to $S$ by
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} |c_n(f_\alpha)|^2=\frac{\sinh^2(\alpha x)}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\alpha^2+n^2}\\
=\frac{\sinh^2(\alpha x)}{\pi^2}\left(2S+\frac{1}{\alpha^2}\right)$$

The right-hand side of \eqref{eqn1} is given by
$$\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} |f_\alpha(x)|^2\:dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{2\alpha x}\:dx=\frac{1}{2\alpha\pi}\sinh(2\alpha\pi)=\frac{1}{\alpha\pi}\cosh(\alpha\pi)\sinh(\alpha\pi)$$

Putting the pieces together gives the desired result (replace $\alpha=\sqrt{x}$)

$$S=\frac{\pi\alpha \coth(\alpha\pi)-1}{2\alpha^2}$$

Comment: This is famous. Have you tried searching for it in this site? You’ll probably find it.

Comment: I have tried indeed, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: The [Poisson summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_summation_formula#Forms_of_the_equation) allows one to prove it.

Comment: One way to prove it is to evaluate $\sum \frac1{z - n^2}$ using residues.

Comment: Or log-differentiating the eulerian product $\frac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x} = \prod\limits_{k=1}^{+\infty}\big(1-\frac{x^2}{k^2}\big)$

Comment: $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \frac{1}{x+n^2}=\int_0^{\infty } \frac{\sin (t)}{-1+e^{t \sqrt{\frac{1}{x}}}} \, dt$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write it as an exercise to you.

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}^{*}$ and $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ the $2\pi$-periodic function given by
$$
f\left(x\right)=\text{cosh}\left(\alpha x \right) \text{ for }x \in \left]-\pi,\pi\right]
$$

- Find the Fourier's coefficient $a_n$ and $b_n$ of $f$.
- Deduce from the previous question both sum
  $$
  \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{n^2+\alpha^2} \text{ as well as }\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+\alpha^2}
  $$
- Take $\alpha=\sqrt{x}$ for $x \in \mathbb{R}^{*+}$ and conclude.

EDIT : 
$f$ is even hence $b_n=0$ and we have with integration by part
$$
\forall n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}, \ a_n=\left(-1\right)^n\frac{2 \alpha\text{sh}\left(\pi \alpha\right)}{\pi\left(n^2+\alpha^2\right)}
$$
and 
$$
\frac{a_0}{2}=\frac{1}{2 \pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\text{cosh}\left(\alpha x\right)\text{d}t=\frac{1}{\alpha \pi}\text{sh}\left(\alpha \pi\right)
$$

> Then we have the equality for $x \in \left]-\pi, \pi\right[$
>   $$
> \cosh\left(\alpha x \right)=\frac{\text{sh}\left(\alpha \pi\right)}{\alpha \pi}+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\left(-1\right)^n\frac{2 \alpha\text{sh}\left(\pi \alpha\right)}{\pi\left(n^2+\alpha^2\right)}
> $$

For $x= \pi $
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2+\alpha^2}=
\frac{\pi \alpha \text{coth}\left(\alpha \pi\right)-1}{2 \alpha^2}
$$

For $x=0$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^n}{n^2+\alpha^2}=
\frac{1}{2 \alpha^2}\left(\frac{\alpha \pi}{\text{sh}\left(\alpha \pi\right)}-1\right)
$$

Comment: I got the expression for the second sum, but since it concerns the sum of positive numbers, Parseval's equality can't seem to give an expression for the first sum $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2+\alpha^2}$. Am I missing something here ?

Comment: I edit to help you see

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\left.\sum_{n \geq 1}{1 \over x + n^{2}}\,\right\vert_{\ x\ >\ 0} & =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
\pars{{1 \over n + 1 - \root{x}\ic} - {1 \over n + 1 + \root{x}\ic}}
{1 \over 2\root{x}\ic}
\\[5mm] & =
{H_{\root{x}\ic} - H_{-\root{x}\ic}\over 2\root{x}\ic}
\qquad\pars{~H_{z}:\ Harmonic\ Number~}
\\[5mm] & =
{H_{\root{x}\ic} -
\bracks{\rule{0pt}{5mm}H_{-1 - \root{x}\ic} + 1/\pars{-\root{x}\ic}} \over 2\root{x}\ic}
\qquad\pars{~H_{z}-Recurrence~}
\\[5mm] & =
{H_{\root{x}\ic} - H_{-1 - \root{x}\ic} \over 2\root{x}\ic} - {1 \over 2x}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pi\cot\pars{\pi\bracks{-\root{x}\ic}} \over 2\root{x}\ic} - {1 \over 2x}
\qquad\pars{~Euler\ Reflection\ Formula~}
\\[5mm] & =
{\pi\ic\coth\pars{\pi\root{x}} \over 2\root{x}\ic} - {1 \over 2x} =
\bbx{\pi\root{x}\coth\pars{\pi\root{x}} - 1\over 2x}
\end{align}

Comment: Can you elaborate on Harmonic numbers ? Series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n+1-\sqrt{x}i}$ is divergent, how can you define a complex number from it ?

Comment: @FlorianOmnès Note that the sum argument in the first line is a difference of two terms: The whole sum $\textsf{converges}$. $\textsf{Harmonic numbers }$ are analytically continued to the complex plane by using the $\textsf{Digamma Function}$. [See this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number).